# Reusable Java StringReader

Tags: java, reader, stringreader

Is there any way of implementing a `StringReader` class that allows reusing the same `StringReader` (or similar functionality) object with more than one strings, without changing any of its functionality (methods)?

For example, such a Java class (say, `ReusableStringReader`) would be a subclass of `java.io.StringReader`, with an extra method like

```
public void reset(String str);
```

which would assign the new string value to the internal `StringReader` parameter, so that all subsequent calls to the `read()` methods of the `StringReader` use the new value. Such a "reusability" is very convenient when one wants to restrict the number of objects used by an application (e.g., one that handles very large number of strings per second via a `Reader` object).

General ways to achieve this would be:

1. **Inheritance.** All the internal state of StringReader is stored in private instance variables, so this is not an option.
2. **Reflection.** Reset the internal state of the `StringReader` object via reflection. There are 4 instance variables to set, which means 4 reflection calls per "reset(String)" call (not too efficient).
3. **Composition.** One could use a reusable `StringInputStream` and from that create a `Reader` object via `InputStreamReader`, then use that `Reader` internally in a subclass of `StringReader`, to implement the full API of the `StringReader` class. This is quite a hack, though.

Any ideas for a better solution?

Comment: Please remove the "off-topic" restriction. This is a very valid question about a potential IMPLEMENTATION that solves a real-world problem, which is very clearly described in the question test. I reworded it to remove the terms "open source implementation", but even that should not have been necessary. There is nothing "opinionated" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are most likely prematurely optimizing a non-problem here, unless you have actually measured to see that `StringReader` instances cause severe GC pressure. It is much more likely that allocations that occur due to reading of content are more meaningful.

So I would not worry at all about reusability: use-once instances are much safer and simpler. In general it is relatively rare to actually benefit from reuse of light-weight objects such as readers.

If you still want to pursue this, however, just write your own `Reader` with `reset()`, and do not worry about JDK variant. You may peek at implementation, but it is dead simple. There's little benefit from trying to sub-class, delegate or compose: especially if you are really concerned amount minimal allocations.

Comment: Using a new `StringReader` per line processed is one approach, as is creating another type of `Reader`. But  what if I wanted a `StringReader`, as per the original question? :-)

Comment: Ah -- is someone expecting a `StringReader` to be passed? If so, a possibility would be to sub-class, but re-implement... mildly wasteful since existing fields would be ignored, and not elegant, but would allow type to be passed as `StringReader` without per-line instantiation. I actually have had to do something similar with another JDK i/o class (I forget which one), when API expected a concrete type.

Comment: Yes, subclassing essentially means copying all the `StringReader` code, only to add a method that does a few assignments. Which is exactly why I posted the question. Thanks and +1. :-)